How to make a series and parallel circuit
I have a problem with making theses combined series and parallel circuit. I'm A beginner of this and this is how i do it:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1493IEiC5z7-M9K94dT-jCITyWeyrTj0g
The look of the switch almost look like this :
https://images.app.goo.gl/DRcPuusAckYtJM3m7
the wire is look likes this (just single plastic shell and small conductor) :
https://images.app.goo.gl/qmdqeytcYqQRQkcr7
What I do is cut the wire cable then combine it by twist the copper the tape it with a transparent tape. For the battery is type d and I uses a small light bulb. I make it cheap as possible. Also, are there any tips on cutting the wire cable plastic shell with out accidentally cut the copper inside?

The first link does not bring up an image.

Twisting and taping wires is really only a temporary solution.  Eventually, the wire will oxidise, and the joints become unreliable.
Ideally, use wire strippers to remove the insulation.  Basic ones can be quite cheap.  It's possible to cut the insulation with a sharp craft knife, then pull off the end of the insulation.
When I was younger, I used to strip wire with my teeth.  Bite into the insulation, pull on the wire, then spit out the bit of insulation.  But now I'm older and my teeth aren't as good as they used to be!
